# In Web2py, how to redirect to another page after user login?

Tags: web2py

**By default, after a successful login the page directs to "default/index". I want it to redirect to some other page.**

This my controller code "user.py"

```
def login():
    form=auth.login()
    if form.process().accepted:
        redirect(URL('page_1'))
    return dict(form=form)
```

This is the view code for "user/login"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="form-container">
     {{=form.custom.begin}}


            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email id" class="string" id="auth_user_email" value="" />

        <input placeholder="Password" name="password" class="password" id="auth_user_password" type="password" class="field" value="" />
            <div class="wrap">
                <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn" value="{{=T('Login')}}" />
                <input name="sign_up" class="btn" type="submit" formaction='/{{=request.application}}/default/user/register' value="{{=T('Sign Up')}}"/>
            </div>
            <input name="Forgot Password" type="submit" class="btn" value="{{=T('Forgot Password')}}" formaction='/{{=request.application}}/default/user/retrieve_password' />
            {{=form.custom.end}}
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

**The thing is, when the form is getting processed, it is still redirecting to the page "default/index".
I don't know where to change this default setting in the system. The code of my controller is not working properly.**

Answer (score 0):

The `auth.login()` action handles the post-login redirect itself, so the redirect will already have happened before the next line in your controller code gets to run.

As described [here](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Auth-Settings-and-messages), where you have your `Auth` settings, you can add:

```
auth.settings.login_next = URL('default', 'page_1')
```

Note, that setting is only the default post-login redirect URL (i.e., if the user goes directly to the login URL). However, if the user is redirected to the login page from another page or arrives at the login page via the default `auth.navbar()` links, the URL will include a `_next` parameter referring back to the original page, and `auth.login()` will therefore redirect back to the referring page (i.e., `auth.login()` first checks for a `_next` parameter in the URL and only uses `auth.settings.login_next` if there is no `_next` parameter). If you want to override this behavior, and always force a redirect to `page_1` regardless of how the user got to the login page, you can pass a `next` argument to `auth.login()`:

```
auth.login(next=URL('default', 'page_1'))
```

The above takes precedence and will override any `_next` parameter in the URL as well as `auth.settings.login_next`.